# new record for each extracted string from a flat file schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a source flat file source schema which has only one node, which will be containing a long string.

```
Demo
  newDemo (length 10)
```

I have a following destination schema

```
Employee
  FName
  LName
```

Now I'm extracting string from the newDemo element of source schema. but I want to create new Employee record for each extracted string.

example: newDemo has value `abcdefghij`. First I extract 1,2 for FName and 3,5 for LName. Again I extract 6,7 For FName and 8,10 for LName.
So I want the output as follows.

```
</Employee>    
  <FullName>
    <FName>ab</>
    <LName>cde</LName>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <FName>fg</>
    <LName>hij</LName>
</Employee>
```

[image]
This map is having the following XSLT.

```
<xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="userCSharp:StringSubstring(string(Demo/text()) , &quot;1&quot; , &quot;5&quot;)" />
    <xsl:variable name="var:v2" select="userCSharp:LogicalExistence(string($var:v1))" />    
<xsl:if test="$var:v2">
          <xsl:variable name="var:v3" select="string(Demo/text())" />
          <xsl:variable name="var:v4" select="userCSharp:StringSubstring($var:v3 , &quot;1&quot; , &quot;5&quot;)" />
          <xsl:variable name="var:v5" select="userCSharp:LogicalNe(string($var:v4) , &quot;A&quot;)" />
          <xsl:variable name="var:v6" select="userCSharp:StringSubstring($var:v3 , &quot;6&quot; , &quot;8&quot;)" />
          <xsl:variable name="var:v7" select="userCSharp:LogicalNe(string($var:v6) , &quot;B&quot;)" />
          <ns0:FullName>
            <xsl:if test="string($var:v5)='true'">
              <fname>
                <xsl:value-of select="$var:v4" />
              </fname>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="string($var:v7)='true'">
              <fname>
                <xsl:value-of select="$var:v6" />
              </fname>
            </xsl:if>
            <lname>
              <xsl:value-of select="$var:v4" />
            </lname>
            <lname>
              <xsl:value-of select="$var:v6" />
            </lname>
          </ns0:FullName>
        </xsl:if>
```

It is putting both FullName and LastName under one FullName while I want two FullName.

Comment: You are probably going to have to write XSLT to achieve this, as it is not something that you can do with the standard functoids as that is not going to create multiple fname & lname elements.

Comment: Sorry, the question isn't too clear.  Can you change the Demo example to some real content?

Comment: Suppose, In my source flat file schema, I have only one element `DATA` which will be a string of 50 characters. In the destination schema I have a `record` which has `two elements`. Now from this `DATA` string I need to extract 5 characters and map to an element in the destination schema.But each time I extract a string  from the DATA and map it to an element in dest schema, I want to create a new record. I don't want the two occurrences in a single record (XSLT snippet above) but I want two records for two occurrences(XML snippet above).

Comment: @v_kumar A sample would be the best way to describe this.  Are the positions always fixed?  How would you know where the names begin and end.